# How to dynamically change CSS elements to be HTTPS or HTTP

Tags: html, css, ssl, https

I have CSS with background-image's elements that refer to another site.
Problem is, that in IE you can't have resources if you are in HTTP while they are in HTTPS and vise versa.

I am using ASP.NET and I want to find a way of letting the CSS know about if it was requested in HTTPS or NOT...

And I MUST use absolute... (its on a different site)

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Just omit the protocol (`http:` or `https:`) in your URLs: `//domain/path/image.png` will use the same protocol as the current page.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be if you can use `relative url` instead of `absolute` in your CSS file while pointing background images.

The problem will gone.

something like:-

```
#div
{
  background-image:url(../images/img1.png);
}
```